# ElasticSearch: Retrieving the latest document for a given timestamp

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, nosql

I have an ElasticSearch database with some documents in it. Each documents has its own timestamp field.

I currently have a WebApi which requires two timestamps, `startTime` and `endTime`. The WebApi simply performs a query on ES to grab the documents which have the timestamps in the given range.

This is my current query:

```
    var readRecords = ElasticClient.Search<SegmentRecord>(s => s
        .Index(ElasticIndexName)
        .Filter(f =>
            f.Range(i =>
                i.OnField(a => a.DateTime).GreaterOrEquals(startTime).LowerOrEquals(endTime))).Size(MaximumNumberOfReturnedDocs).SortAscending(p => p.DateTime)).Documents;
```

Very simple, it's basically a range query based on the `startTime` and `endTime` parameters. And it works. :-)

Now the problem is: I need to retrieve even the latest document which has got a timestamp lower than `startTime`.
So basically the final query should be:

- all the document in the range [`startTime`, `endTime`]

AND

- the latest document in time which has a timestamp < `startTime`

the first part obviously can return any number of records, zero, just one or many

the second part should return just one document, (or zero if doesn't exist any document prior to `starTime`)

Comment: I think you either need two queries or, keep the current query for the list of 0 or many docs and add an aggregations section where you get the "latest document in time". Then when trying to make a sense of what you got back you need to look at both `hits` section and `aggs` section.

Comment: thanks! please, could you elaborate your answer a little bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this I meant in my comment above:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "time": {
            "gte": "2015-06-04",
            "lte": "2015-06-05"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "global_all_docs_agg": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "filter_for_min": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "time": {
                "lte": "2015-06-04"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "min_date": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "time": "asc"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "sss",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "time": "2015-06-05"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "sss",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "time": "2015-06-04"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "sss",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "time": "2015-06-05"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "global_all_docs_agg": {
         "doc_count": 6,
         "filter_for_min": {
            "doc_count": 4,
            "min_date": {
               "hits": {
                  "total": 4,
                  "max_score": null,
                  "hits": [
                     {
                        "_index": "sss",
                        "_type": "test",
                        "_id": "5",
                        "_score": null,
                        "_source": {
                           "time": "2015-06-01"
                        },
                        "sort": [
                           1433116800000
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

The list between `startTime` and `endTime` is under `hits`. The minimum lower than `startTime` is under `aggregations`.

Comment: There's one problem, though, it seems. The aggregation will return only the minimum value, not the entire document matching the min value.

Comment: Actually, I found a way. I updated the query in my answer. The solution is to replace `min` aggregation with a `top_hits` + `sort` aggregation.